# Visual Studios commenting plugin / add-in?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there a plugin / add in for Visual Studio 2012 that will allow me to make comments resembling the ones made on Google Drive. I enjoy how you can have text highlighted and have the comment outside of the text.

This is an example of Google Drive's comment system.

[image: Google Drive's Comment system]

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I found to your description is the [**StickyNotes**](http://stickynotes4code.com) plugin for Visual Studio:

> It is a Visual Studio plug in that seamlessly integrates with the IDE providing sticky notes capabilities to documents within a solution.
>
> While several methods exist for lightweight code review, such as "over the shoulder" reviews, review by email and meetings, the most effective reviews are conducted by tools to facilitate the process.
>
> StickyNotes© gives your team an efficient and lightweight way to benefit from the power of code review with inline commenting.
>
> With StickyNotes© your team can conduct the most efficient reviews and can fully realize the benefits of code review.
>
> StickyNotes© can also be used for individual purposes to write reminders or todos.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

While the site mentions VS 2008/2008 SP1/2010, I don't know whether 2012 is supported. You can try the trial version or contact the author. Unfortunately it's not completely free, but perhaps worth it if it'll really help you.

Comment: Yes I found that also it's just not what I'm looking for however. Sadly what I really need in order to understand it is pretty much a copy of what google drive does yet in the VS2012 IDE. :(

Comment: I've been looking around after reading your previous comment. Will let you know if I find anything more suited to your requirements, especially something that's free.

Comment: I defiantly will! Are you interested in it also? Personally I beleive this ability would help a good deal of people tremendously and make work easier and more effective. This is especially true when it comes to large scale production where communication and understanding ideas is vital.

Comment: Hadn't considered it before you suggested it, but sounds like a good idea. Maybe someone's interested in creating such a plugin, if one doesn't already exist. Let's see...